# Laravel HHVM DB insert cuts off decimal numbers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, hhvm

I noticed that a DB insert with floating numbers using HHVM is cutting off the decimal part. In the example below, the value actually stored in the MySQL database is 7.00. The MySQL field is a decimal field.

```
DB::table('test')->insert([
    [
        'name'        => 'Some name',
        'description' => 'Some description',
        'price'       => 7.99
    ]);
```

When using PHP instead of HHVM, the value is stored correctly. Also, when replacing `7.99` with `'7.99'` (as a string) using HHVM, the value is also stored correctly.

Is this an incompatibility between Laravel's `insert()` function and HHVM, or am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i know this is late but its not laravel cutting it off, its your database you probably have it set to an INT set the column to double and it will be fine.